# how to remove dynamic components from array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-dynamic-components

I can't cope with proper rendering after removing an element using `deleteData()` from an array of objects that simultaneously serves to create dynamic components.

The element gets removed correctly but it acts as if the component didn't know that it should refresh, and Vue does not know that the data has changed.

In the chrome Vue extension, the correct element is removed, but the Vue in the DOM removes the last element()

Vue:

```
 <template>
  <b-container>
    <SectionSelector :AddSection="AddSection"/>
      <component v-for="(section, index) in sections"
              :key="index"
              :is="section.type"
              :sectionIndex="index"
              :sectionData="section[index]"
              :deleteData="deleteData"
              @sectionDataEmit="sectionDataEmit"/>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
  import SectionSelector from './components/SectionSelector.vue';
  import FullText from './components/sections/FullText.vue';
  import FullImage from './components/sections/FullImage.vue';
  import ImageRightTextLeft from './components/sections/ImageRightTextLeft.vue';
  import ImageLeftTextRight from './components/sections/ImageLeftTextRight.vue';
  import Vue from 'vue'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        sections: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      AddSection(sectionData) {
        this.sections.push(sectionData);
      },
      updateSection(sectionIndex, sectionData) {
        Vue.set(this.sections, sectionIndex, sectionData);
      },
      sectionDataEmit(emitData) {
        Vue.set(this.sections, emitData.position, emitData.content);
      },
      deleteData(index) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line 
        console.log(index)
        this.$delete(this.sections, index);
      }
    },
    components: {
      SectionSelector,
      FullText,
      FullImage,
      ImageRightTextLeft,
      ImageLeftTextRight
    }
  }
</script>
```

component:

```
    <template>
  <b-row>
    <h3>Full text {{ sectionIndex+1 }}</h3>
    <b-button variant="danger"
            @click="deleteButton(sectionIndex)">delete</b-button>
    <b-textarea :value="sectionData" 
              @input="sectionDataEmit" />
  </b-row>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['sectionIndex', 'sectionData', 'deleteData'],
    methods: {
      sectionDataEmit(value) {
        let emitData = {
          position: this.sectionIndex,
          content: {
            type: 'FullText',
            fields: {
              text: value
            }
          }
        }
        this.$emit('sectionDataEmit', emitData)
      },
      deleteButton(index) {
        this.deleteData(index)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

[before deleteData()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBxiS.jpg)

[after deleteData()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb9rZ.jpg)

Comment: The example is not clear and not meaningful. Can you please consider adding appropriate [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: edited, I'm sorry, it should be better now

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to render a list of stateful components and not plain/simple DOM nodes, it becomes critical to have **a key** as a really unique attribute. Using an index as a key attribute value does not guarantee uniqueness. You can read more about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State).

### Why does this happen?

Vue.js uses Virtual DOM (VDOM) internally for efficient rendering of the UI. So when your array changes, Vue.js uses VDOM to update the DOM. VDOM has no knowledge of Vue.js component or its state. So, there is a chance that VDOM may assign a wrong DOM element to a component. This is where **the key** attribute helps Vue.js to keep track of components and its DOM element.

#### What happens when you use `index` for `key` attribute?

Imagine you have use index as a key attribute. Now, you have initially five items in an array to render. For each item, it instantiates a component instance. So, five DOM elements and five component

- component0 - DOM0 - index 0
- component1 - DOM1 - index 1
- component2 - DOM2 - index 2
- component3 - DOM3 - index 3
- component4 - DOM4 - index 4

Now, say you remove the 3rd item using splice method:

```
array.splice(2, 1);
```

After doing the above operation, array length changes from 5 to 4. For vue.js, it is the 4th index i.e. fifth item is gone. Index 2 is still there and never gone; thus its associated **component2** is still valid. So instead, it goes and kills the **component4** referred by **index 4** (since index 4 no longer exists for this array). In short, it destroys the wrong component.

- component0 - DOM0 - index 0
- component1 - DOM1 - index 1
- component2 - DOM2 - index 2
- component3 - DOM3 - index 3
- <s>component4 - DOM4 - index 4</s>

#### Solution?

You should have some unique key, `id`, for each `sectionData` to uniquely identify itself in the list. Imagine, if you have to sort `sections` array, that unique id should still be the same even after sorting (using **index** for **id** will change its id after reordering and things gets messed up with VDOM).

Read more about [these rules here on this Vue.js forum thread](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/simple-clarification-of-when-using-key-with-v-for-is-appropriate-and-why/28966).